# Creating a script that creates a shortcut and then restarts the computer

Tags: vbscript, shortcut, shortcut-file

I need help with my code. I am trying to make a script that does 2 things: First, it creates shortcut icon on the users desktop. Second, when the user double clicks the icon a box appears asking if they want to restart their computer giving them the option to click OK to restart to CANCEL to cancel the command. When entering the script into the command prompt it just executes the restart computer option. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my script:

```
    Dim answer


' ********* Main processing section **********

' Verify that the user wants to open the Turn Off Computer dialog
    Set wshObject = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    desktopFolder = wshObject.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    Set myShortcut = wshObject.CreateShortcut(desktopFolder & "\\Shortcut.lnk")
    myShortcut.TargetPath = "%windir%\Shortcut.exe"
    myShortcut.Save()

    answer = MsgBox("The Turn Off Computer dialog will be opened.", 1, "Turn off Computer Script!")
    If answer = 1 then  ' User clicked on OK
    Initiate_Logoff()
    End if

' *********** Procedures go here *************

' Open the Windows Turn Off Computer dialog
    Function Initiate_Logoff()
    shellApp.ShutdownWindows
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Option Explicit

'create a desktop shortcut
Dim shl : Set shl = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim scut : Set scut = shl.CreateShortcut(shl.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%") & "\Desktop\Shortcut.lnk")
scut.TargetPath = "%windir%\shortcut.exe"
scut.Save

Dim cmd : cmd = "shutdown.exe /r /t 1" 'this command restarts the machine

'if the script is being run by cscript (command line)
If InStr(WScript.FullName, "cscript") > 0 Then
  shl.Exec cmd
Else
  'else ask the user
  If MsgBox("Restart Now?", vbQuestion + vbOKCancel, "Title") = vbOK Then
    shl.Exec cmd
  End If
End If

WScript.Quit
```